# How to get programmatically the source of the pasteboard content on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

On iOS 14, when the user copy/paste content on another app, a notification is displayed with the name of the application where the pasteboard content came from :

[image: On this example, the text is pasted to Notes app from Safari app]

Is it possible to get this information programmatically ?

For example, if the user copy a link on Safari and paste it on my app, can the app know the pasteboard content came from Safari ?

I didn't find anything like that on UIPasteboard or UIPasteConfiguration documentation.

Comment: using `UIPasteboard.hasURLs` before copy/paste can avoid receiving some notifications

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no API to get the `owner` who put the item in `pasteboard`.

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH11-SW30):

> **Pasteboard Owner and Items**
>
> The object that last put data onto the
> pasteboard is referred to as the pasteboard owner. Each piece of data
> placed onto a pasteboard is considered a pasteboard item. The
> pasteboard can hold single or multiple items. Apps can place or
> retrieve as many items as they wish. For example, say a user selection
> in a view contains both text and an image. The pasteboard lets you
> copy the text and the image to the pasteboard as separate items. An
> app reading multiple items from a pasteboard can choose to take only
> those items that it supports (the text, but not the image, for
> example).

The [addItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622101-additems) method, does not have (or maybe I couldn't find it) any property named `owner`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no method or property that we can retrieve for `UIPasteBoard`

Below is the **Note** from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard)

> Starting in iOS 14, the system notifies the user when an app gets
> general pasteboard content that originated in a different app.

They say it is system generated notification. So, I think we can't retrieve the origin app name programmatically.

However, they have provided methods for detecting pattern, but not sure if this will be of any help.

> Use the methods described in `Detecting Patterns of Content in Pasteboard Items` to determine if pasteboard items match various
> patterns, such as web search terms, URLs, or numbers, without
> notifying the user.

Comment: Yes, I saw detecting patterns. But patterns can't filter from source neither. Or am I missing something ?